# Difference between FormClosed and FormClosing event

Tags: vb.net, forms

In `VB.NET` what is the difference between `FormClosed` and `FormClosing` event?

```
Private Sub frmTerminal_TCP_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing

End Sub


Private Sub frmTerminal_TCP_FormClosed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed

End Sub
```

Comment: read the remarks section of the MSDN documentation  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed(v=vs.110).aspx   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: ... which is the answer to many questions posted here

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`FormClosing` happens before `FormClosed`. Think of `FormClosing` like the dialog that ask you to save your document before quitting the program. It gives you an opportunity to cancel the window's termination.

`FormClosed` is triggered after the form has closed. From [MS documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The FormClosed event occurs after the form has been closed by the user or by the Close method or the Exit method of the Application class. To prevent a form from closing, handle the FormClosing event and set the Cancel property of the CancelEventArgs passed to your event handler to true.